# Flaticon, import icon with different content name

Tags: css

I it possible to use an flat icon with different content name ? I want to add new icon to existing project so I download flaticon as font icon. But its conflict previous icon set.

```
.flaticon-alert:before { content: "\f100"; }
```

Is there any way to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

The icon fonts are fonts, so for 2 icon sets that use the same character ("content") you just have to ensure that the class name also specifies the font-face:

styles.css

```
.flaticon-alert:before {
  font-family: flaticon; // or name given in flaticon's @font-face css
}
```

flaticon.css example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: flaticon;
  src: url(flaticon.woff);
}
```

Comment: do we use class as same way we did or do we need to change ? I just did and nothing happened

Comment: No need to change the class name. Order the stylesheets: flaticon, other stylesheet (like font-awesome), then your custom stylesheet. Then check flaticon's stylesheet for the font-face name. Then do the above with the font-face name you found. If that doesn't work, mod your question to show the error you're getting that tells you this "conflict" exists.